# Can 1 site analyzed by 2 analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Because I have to look for my clients Adwords campaign, and it can't be with my analytics acc ...

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

One of the variables in the Analytics code that you put on your page is:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '***account code here ***']);
```

so if I am understanding it correctly, you would have to have two sets of tracking code for the page.  They may or may not interfere with one another, I'm not sure, but it would be a bit messy.  You'd also have to rename some of the variables in the second set of tracking code, at the very least - to avoid declaring the same variables twice.